# checkout code using git between two revisions in a seperate directory

Tags: git

I am trying to checkout the code from git repo to my local directory.

I want to checkout just specific amount of changes which is made between 2 revisions and not the whole code to be checked ou so i can publish the changes made to the code on server.

Its like svncheckout in which you mention the revision no and the changes get checked out and then you can publish the code on server.

I tried various ways but didn't find a very useful way to do that.
I also tried git checkout but that is checking out the whole code from the repo.

If anyone can help me on this that would be very great.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're just trying to get the diff between two commits (or a series of commits) and then automatically apply that diff to a different copy of the repository. Try using the various patch commands. You use format-patch -*n* to generate a patch file from the last *n* commits.

```
    $ git format-patch -3
```

That will generate a patch file (basically a coded diff file) for all the changes in the last 3 commits. Then you apply the patch using the am command.

```
    $ git am /path/to/patch-file
```

I strongly suggest reading up on the patch commands before using them. Syncing up repositories without using a shared remote can result in all kinds of merge conflicts and resolving them through the patching system is a little different than resolving normal merge issues.